# PLayframework app not running with netbeans

Tags: playframework

Running netbeans 7.1 and i get this

```
nb-run-application:
C:\play\play-1.2.4\id doesn't exist
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8005
Java Result: -1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

This just started occuring. reverted code and still same issue. Are there any logs written that can shed a better light?

The ide shows app running for a few seconds and then it shuts down

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that there was a closing tag missing and the ide did not show that error. caught it with using compare to code in back up repository